# Copying an array and changing the values? Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code

Tags: java

> Write a method that takes a reference to an array of integers values and two integers oldVal and newVal, and that creates and returns a new array that is a copy of the original array, but in which all occurrences of the value oldVal are replaced with the value newVal.

CAN ANYONE TELL ME WHAT I AM DOING WRONG HERE?

```
public static int[] copyReplace(int[] values, int oldVal, int newVal) {
    int[] b = values.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (values[i] == oldVal) {
            oldVal = newVal;
        }
        b[i] = values[i];
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Did you tried to run this code?

Comment: This shouldn't even compile because `int[] b = values.length;` isn't the correct way to create a new array.

Comment: You are setting the array b equal to something that is not an array.

Comment: int[] b = values.length;

returns integer not an integer array.

Comment: @Pavlo He can't have run it because it doesn't even compile.

Comment: In addition to the initialization of `int[] b`, the line `oldVal = newVal;` won't have the effect you intend: you need to modify the value in the returned array, not the local copy of `oldVal`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you think that `oldVal = newVal;` will do and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, this isn't the correct way to create an array:

```
int[] b = values.length;
```

I assume that you were trying to create an array of that length:

```
int[] b = new int[values.length];
```

Also, even once you make this change, this line won't do what you think it does:

```
oldVal = newVal;
```

This won't have any effect whatever on the value in the array - all you're doing is changing the local variable. I assume that you meant to do something like this:

```
if(values[i] == oldVal){
    b[i] = newVal;                   
}
else
{
    b[i] = values[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things are wrong here that I can see off the bat.

First you can't set `b = values.length;` b is an array, and values.length is an integer. You should be doing this if your intent is to copy the array. `b = values;`.

Next, in your forloop, you are simply setting your old values integer to the new value. `oldVal = newVal` should be changed to `values[i] = newVal`. However, this will change your original array, and not the new one you are supposed to be returning. So instead it should be `b[i] = newVal;`

The final product should like something like this:

```
public static int[] copyReplace(int[] values, int oldVal, int newVal){

       int[] b = values;

        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){

            if(values[i] == oldVal){

                b[i] = newVal;                   
            }          
    }

    return b;                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with some comments

```
public static int[] copyReplace(int[] values, int oldVal, int newVal){

   //Here when you declare b, you need to declare it as an int[]
   //You declared yours as just a plain old integer rather than an array 
   //with the size you want
   int[] b = new int[values.length];


    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){

        if(values[i] == oldVal){
            //You had the correct if statement but what you really want to 
            //be doing is copying the desired value into the new array
            b[i] = newVal;

        } else {
            //The other case is to keep the value the same as the old array
            b[i] = values[i];
        }
    }
   return b;
   }
```